# moment.js Compare dates with with the format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: momentjs

I have two input fields with dates formatted as dd-mm-yyyy.

fromdate: 10-06-2021

todate: 14-06-2021

I would like to compare the dates with moment.js, but the result is that fromdate is bigger than todate.

```
var dateFrom = moment($(".fromdate").val(), "dd-mm-yyyy");
var dateTo = moment($(".todate").val(), "dd-mm-yyyy");

if(moment(dateFrom).isBefore(dateTo, 'day')){
    console.log("Go");
} else {
    console.log("Stop");
}
```

My console prints Stop.

I use moment-with-locales.js

Answer (score 0):

If we add a `console.log` to check the MomentJS objects, we can see that the parsing went wrong:

```js
console.log(dateFrom, dateTo);
// "2020-12-31T23:06:00.000Z" "2020-12-31T23:06:00.000Z"
```

```js
var dateFrom = moment('10-06-2021', "dd-mm-yyyy");
var dateTo = moment('14-06-2021', "dd-mm-yyyy");

console.log(dateFrom, dateTo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

---

Your second parameters (date format) are incorrect.

MomentJs needs the following format: `DD-MM-YYYY` instead off `dd-mm-yyyy` where

- `DD` Day of month
- `MM` Month number
- `YYYY` 4 digit year

For more formatting, check there [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```js
var dateFrom = moment('10-06-2021', "DD-MM-YYYY");
var dateTo = moment('14-06-2021', "DD-MM-YYYY");

if(moment(dateFrom).isBefore(dateTo, 'day')){
    console.log("Go");
} else {
    console.log("Stop");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

> Go